# I want to make a plot in R with ggplot but it gives me a value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a barplot with ggplot2. This is the dataset (Error should be in the `x`, and cantidad as `y`):

[image: Error should be in the x, and cantidad as y]

When I run this:

```
grafico <- ggplot(tipoerror, aes(x = Error, y = Cantidad))
```

I have no plot in the plots section. I have a new value in the environment instead.

Can you help me to see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you've assigned the plot to `grafico`, to display it use `print(grafico)`. But you may find it useful to add a layer such as `+ geom_point()`

Answer (score 1):

There are several minor/beginners errors (most of them already mentioned in other comments or answers) which add up:

1. In the call to `aes` the parameter `y = Cantidad` is written with a capital `C` while the image shows the header uses lower case `c`.
2. The created `ggplot` object is missing a layer, i.e, `ggplot` doesn't know *what* to plot.
3. The `ggplot` object `grafico` was created but not printed. This is why a new object appears in the *Environment* pane of RStudio but the plot is not shown in the *Plots* pane.

Please, try:

```
library(ggplot2)
grafico <- ggplot(tipoerror, aes(x = Error, y = cantidad)) + 
  geom_col()
grafico
```

to produce this chart:

[image]

#### Data

As the OP failed to provide data in a reproducible format, I had to make up some sample data

```
tipoerror <- data.frame(
  Error = c(NA, LETTERS[1:9]),
  cantidad = c(309, 149, 91, 80, 79, 42, 39, 22,  5,  3)
)
```

where the letters replace the error messages.

Comment: Thank you! Just strating out, so this is really helpful. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Great explanation of each of the mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is already summarised, you need to add stat = "identity". As mentioned in the comments, you will also need layer. In this case, geom_bar.

```
library(ggplot)
er <- data.frame(A = c("John", "Erik", "David"), Count = c(39, 49, 68))
er
ggplot(er, aes(x = A, y = Count)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```